# Why graalvm is not appearing in update-alternatives --config java?

Tags: java, path, tar, ubuntu-20.04

I downloaded the file `graalvm-ce-java17-linux-amd64-22.3.0.tar.gz` and extract to the location `usr/lib/jvm`.

Then i set the environment path with command
`export PATH=/path/to/<graalvm>/bin:$PATH` and
`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/<graalvm>`

After that i tried to run  `sudo update-alternatives --config java` but could not find the list of installed graalvm java.

Other java version installed from terminal are shown but manual download setup java not appear in update-alternatives --config java.

Comment: `update-alternatives` is part of the `dpkg` system. Why do you expect it to recognize manually installed programs? If it did, how would it be able to determine the version number?

Answer (score 1):

Manually it won't recognize by update-alternatives. In order to do that, we have to provide following command in terminal :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/<graalvm>/bin/java 4
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /path/to/<graalvm>/bin/javac 4
```

This will add into the list of *`update-alternatives`* database of dpkg system. Next time whenever you run `update-alternatives --config java` command, it will appear in terminal.

Additional Info:

Here 4 number represent the priority order , you can set highest number than any other priority number set for jdk so in ***auto*** mode it pick up jdk with highest priority number.

Beside this work for other jdk that is downloaded manually as tar or zip file.